# Apache with Tomcat proxy: not showing images

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat

I've set up an Apache httpd server proxying requests to Tomcat using mod_proxy, listening on port 80. My only problem is that the static images and css is not appearing properly. If I use Tomcat as a server by itself on port 8080, the images and css appear fine. Any ideas how to display them? Thanks!

Note: I'm on a Mac and am using an Amazon EC2 server. An example would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out guys- please don't kick me when you read this. I'm using Apache2 with Spring 3, with Springsource Tool Suite as the IDE. The whole reason I wasn't able to get it running is because I was using this in my index jsp file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:url value="/resources/styles/foo.css" htmlEscape="true" />" type="text/css"/>
```

The thing is, that when run on a Tomcat 7 server, its perfect. However, when run on an apache 2 server with tomcat as the container, this css file wasn't showing up. So I removed the `/` from `/resources/styles/foo.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:url value="resources/styles/foo.css" htmlEscape="true" />" type="text/css"/>
```

It then worked perfectly, on both Apache+Tomcat and Tomcat standalone.

Thanks and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

This issue refers to Path Translation, you might going to serve you'r application to the client at the top level /, but  the corresponding path would be /myapp/(for example).
Servlet applications running under tomcat are often setup in this way to provide multiple applications in one, you'r apache setup looks like it :

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
```

you'r back-end application (myapp) is not aware of this translation and still hands out it's usual paths.
for example you'r application refers to some static image files served by application running in tomcat at the location /myapp/images/, 
one of the way you can to do is keep special proxy mappings  apart from other rewrite rules.

```
ProxyPass /myapp/images http://localhost:8080/myapp/images

ProxyPassReverse /myapp/images http://localhost:8080/myapp/images
```

so you can use these lines in front of previous directive block.

Comment: How this will work if we have a load balancer setup ?  how to make the path dynamic

Answer (score 0):

In apache there is htdocs folder in that create a folder with name same as your project folder and paste resources in that and restart the server.

Comment: where does the htdocs folder lie? do i have to create one myself? if so, where?

Comment: You can find the directory at the following location.

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs

The path can vary as per your installation directory and inside the htdocs folder you need to specify the root folder of your application. For example, if your application is deployed with "Web" name then you need to create folder named this in the path specified and inside that folder you need to put your static resources, like images in your case. Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your apache error log will contain 404's for the images, note the URL's being used and either:

- compare them to the ProxyPass directive you used and fix/add ProxyPass
- Copy them to the right subdirectory of your webservers documentroot